# `xcodebuild archive` always performs a clean build

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, cocoapods, xcodebuild

Every time I run `xcodebuild ...params... archive` it performs a clean build without reusing the cache from a previous build.

While I understand the motivation behind it, it has serious consequences on my CI build times because I generate an IPA for every push. Since my workspace has a `Pods` project (unlikely to change between commits) and an `App` project (changing all the time) I'm looking for a way to cache the `Pods` compilation phase somehow – which `xcodebuild archive` doesn't seem to allow.

Is there a way to force using the cache when archiving? Is there any other way to cache the archived version of `Pods`?

Comment: Interesting. Which exact Xcode version are you using?